# "Back" command for org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I type `C-c C-v` to see the list of TODOs, or `C-c / m` to see headlines with a certain tag, org-mode shows me a sparse tree with the results.

---

How do I then go back to seeing the tree the way it was before I issued this command? Note that I haven't changed the file in any way, so this isn't your normal "undo", it's about going back to how org-mode was displaying the tree before.

Answer (score -1):

M-x show-all

You can bind this to a key of your choice, either globally or in the org-mode keymap.

Comment: This doesn't send you back to the state the tree was before, right? It expands _the whole_ tree?

Comment: Yes, you are right